# $locationChangeSuccess doesn't wait for route resolve

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

Angular 1.4.10

In my application I use $routeProvider with asynchronous resolution.

I have a form with a submit button that, when form is submitted and request is success **we do a redirection**.

The redirection could affect the route, or only the $location.search(). I would like to listen for both changes, to show a message once all is finished (request, redirection and/or async resolution of the route).

If I use **$routeChangeSuccess**, it's only fired if path changes, and it waits to the resolution in the routeProvider, but it's not fired if only $location.search() changes.

If I use **$locationChangeSuccess**, it's fired if path or search changes, the problem is that , ***it doesn't wait for routeProvider async resolution***.

The only solution I find for now is, to process the newUrl and oldUrl,if the path will be changed, listen for $routeChangeSuccess, otherwise listen for $locationChangeSuccess, or nothing if the oldUrl is the same than newUrl.

I would like to avoid this extra processing. Any idea?

Comment: sounds like an XY problem. Instead of describing your issue, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: _show a message once all is finished (request, redirection and/or async resolution of the route)._

Comment: The problem is that I want to listen for the changes that $locationChangeSuccess listen, but it does not wait for route resolving, as my route resolution is asynchronous.